# WPF GridViewHeader styling questions

Tags: wpf, gridview

I'm trying to set up my very first WPF ListView/GridView and having trouble with styling the column headers.  I currently have 3 issues.  Here is a view of the GridView as it is right now:

[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3245/wpfgridview.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/3245/wpfgridview.png)

1. I want to remove the little white vertical borders that separate the column headers.
2. I want to remove the MouseOver effect.  This screenshot has the mouse over the 3rd column which turns the background to white.
3. How can I override the horizontal alignment on a single column without screwing it up?

This is what the code looks like:

```
<Style x:Key="GrayHeader" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
   <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
         <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#373638" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#57595B" />
         </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5, 5" />
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource 
                                        EmployeeInfoDataSource}}" 
          Margin="0,20,0,20">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"  >
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="#7BB3DC" />
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#000000" />
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

   <ListView.View>
      <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="false" 
                ColumnHeaderToolTip="Employee Information"
                ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GrayHeader}"
                >
         <GridViewColumn Width="200" Header="First Name">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>

         <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="LastName">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
               </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>

         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EmployeeNumber}" 
                         Width="200" Header="Employee Number"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

### EDITED:

To be clear about the 3rd question I had.  This is the code:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="300">
    <GridViewColumnHeader HorizontalAlignment="Right">
       Last Name
    </GridViewColumnHeader>
```

That produces this. It works but there is that extra white space in there to the left of the actual text now.

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/3783/wpfgridviewcolumnheader.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/3783/wpfgridviewcolumnheader.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out my issues.  The problem was that the column header acted like a button, so a new template had to be applied.  Changing it to a TextBlock removed all of those issues.

```
<Style x:Key="GridHeaderCenter" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock.Background>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#373638" />
                                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#77797B" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </TextBlock.Background>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#373638" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#77797B" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

<GridViewColumn Width="100" HeaderContainerStyle="{ StaticResource GridHeaderCenter}" Header="Transfer">
```